# Passing props to active react router handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement simple CRUD functionality with react, using react router for different routes.

My routes are defined like this:

```
<Route path="locations" component={LocationPage}>
  <IndexRoute component={LocationsView}/>
  <Route path="create" component={LocationCreate}/>
  <Route path=":locationSlug">
    <IndexRoute component={LocationsView}/>
    <Route path="edit" component={LocationEdit}/>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

The current way I'm rendering different components is like this in `LocationPage`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Locations</h1>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem with this is that I have no way of passing down props into each of the sub-components, i.e. each of the sub-components would have to fetch its own state manage it. But that seems ridiculous, since it's clear they're one logical unit, and only `LocationPage` would need to know and keep state about any locations. Idealy, I'd like to pass the locations as props to the sub-components, but I don't see how I could do it this way.

I've seen examples like this on the web:

```
<RouteHandler {...this.state}/>
```

and this would fix my problem, but I can't seem to get this to work. I assume it's long been depricated, since much of the information about it on the internet is outdated.

I don't really see how I could pass props to `this.props.children` without doing some magic with cloning, and adding props that way, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Are there any recommended ways of doing this, or any good solutions to this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply implementing my own `RouteHandler`. The implementation:

```
export default (props) => {
  // prevent childception
  let propsToPass = {};
  Object.keys(props).forEach(key =>
    (key.localeCompare('children') !== 0) && (propsToPass[key] = props[key])
  );
  return <div>
    {props.children && React.cloneElement(props.children, { ...propsToPass })}
  </div>
}
```

And the usage:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Locations</h1>
      <RouteHandler
        locations={this.props.locations}
        selectedLocation={this.props.selectedLocation}>
        {this.props.children}
      </RouteHandler>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This achieves my desired functionality without introducing too much boilerplate into the code. Hopefully, this might help someone, if anyone ever runs into this issue.

I ended up not really using this, as eventually, this component got far too large and had far too much responsibility for my liking, so I did eventually end up moving the processing logic into the sub-components, which seemed like the lesser of two evils.

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept is to iterate through the children, cloning them and inserting in the state and props of the current component. Then the function returns the [cloned](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) children. See below:

```
render: function () {

    return (
        <div>
           <h1>Locations</h1>
           {this._renderedChildren()}
        </div>
    );
  },

  _renderedChildren: function () {
    var renderedChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
      function (child) {
        return React.cloneElement(
        child, Object.assign({}, this.state, this.props)
        );
      }.bind(this)
    );
    return renderedChildren;
  }
```

`Object.assign({}, this.state, this.props)` is merging this.state and this.props.
`React.cloneElement(child, props)` makes a new react element with designated props.

Comment: This seems overly complicated for the simple functionality I want to achieve. Using this approach would require me introduce boilerplate into each component that I would like to introduce this functionality to.